# KeyEvent.getKeyCode() always returns zero

Tags: java, swing

I am working on a pause key in my little school project, but for some reason it refuses to work. Using this code :

```
     public void keyTyped(KeyEvent me) { //ESCAPE PLS WORK ... 
        code = me.getKeyCode();
        System.out.println(code);
}
```

For some reason "code" always stays zero. I tried to put it in different voids(pressed/released etc), but it still does not work. What could be the reason?

Comment: Is this a `KeyListener` attached to some sort of `Frame`? Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem?

Comment: I add the key listener to the frame, yes. I add it by this.addKeyListener(this);

Comment: Also, you shouldn't call methods _voids_. If anything, say _`void` methods_

Comment: Please update your question to give us a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Note that [For `KEY_TYPED` events, the keyCode is `VK_UNDEFINED` (0)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyCode()).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not try the `keyPressed()` method again as in the example below:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int code = e.getKeyCode();
    switch( code ) { 
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            // handle up 
            System.out.println(code);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            // handle down 
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            // handle left
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT :
            // handle right
            break;
     }
}
```

Note that you must expect an integer.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) says about `getKeyCode()`

> Returns: the integer code for an actual key on the keyboard. (For `KEY_TYPED` events, the keyCode is `VK_UNDEFINED`.)

And the value of `VK_UNDEFINED` is zero.

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) also says:

> ```
> public static final int KEY_TYPED
> ```
>
> The "key typed" event. This event is generated when a character is entered. In the simplest case, it is produced by a single key press. Often, however, characters are produced by series of key presses, and the mapping from key pressed events to key typed events may be many-to-one or many-to-many.

So maybe you are looking at the wrong kind of key events.  Maybe should be looking at the `KEY_PRESSED` or `KEY_RELEASED` events rather than the `KEY_TYPED` events.